# Specific svg file size

Tags: svg, affinity-designer

I want to export my logo from affinity to .svg in specific size, but affinity always sets size for 100% width and 100% height. Where can i change it?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option to control the viewBox called `Set viewBox` in the Export Options palette (when you are working with the Export Persona)

According to [this post](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/8099-set-svg-tag-heightwidth-to-pixel-dimension-on-export/) in the official forum it toggles between this 2 behaviors:

- `<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" […]`
- `<svg width=40px height=40px […]`

I attached a screenshot of the Export Options palette:

[image: Screenshot of the Export Options palette]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the native size of an SVG by opening it in an XML-capable text editor (a text editor that can do UTF-8 with UNIX line endings, typically an HTML editor will edit XML just fine.)

The width and height are attributes of the svg tag:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="128" height="128" viewBox="0, 0, 128, 128">
```

You will also want to set the viewBox attribute (if it is there,) which is 4 comma-separated numbers that describe top, left, x, and y. Typically, you will want top and left to be 0, and x to be the same as the width, and y to be the same as the height.

You can also set the displayed size of an svg with CSS when it is placed in a website:

So you may want to leave your SVG at a native size of 100% width and height and just modify its size with CSS in whatever contexts that you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you rendering this SVG? I assume it's in a web browser?

If that's the case, browsers will automatically scale SVGs to the maximum size that it can show.

But, if you were using the SVG in a website, you would just set the image size in the HTML:

```
<img src="your-svg.svg" width="300px" alt="Logo" />
```

It will figure the height out itself.

It would be good if you could link the SVG here too so we can see how it's constructed. Affinity Designer is supposed to be quite good, but it hasn't got a large base of users at the moment.